# How to format the time in this Google Apps Script

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script, javascript, time-zone, google-sheets-custom-function

I want to format a Google Sheet cell when I read it in my script but it comes out 25 minutes later.
The cell's time is `20:00:00` but the output is `20:25`. I am using this

```
var formattedDate = Utilities.formatDate(time, "GMT+2", HH:mm");
```

Without using it the time comes as `1899-12-30T18:25:08.000Z` even though the cell's content is `20:00:00`. Any ideas?

Comment: Set your locale correctly in settings

Answer (score 1):

The way that Sheets and Apps Script handle "dates" are very different.

- For Sheets the "date" unit is 1 day; The base date is `1899-12-30 0:00:00`, getting the timezone from the spreadsheet settings.
- For Apps Script, which is based on JavaScript, the "date" unit is 1 millisecond. The base date is `1970-1-1 00:00:00 UTC`.

Below is an example script that if the active cell has `20:00:00` it will add `"25:00"` to the cell to the right.

```
function myFunction() {
  /* Assume that cell value is 8:00:00 pm.
  The displayed value depends on spreadsheet settings and cell format */
  var range = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveRange(); // See Apps Script documentation


  var value = range.getValue(); // This returns a date object;

  var time = value.getTime(); // See JavaScript documentation

  var delta = 25 * 60 * 1000; // Convert 25 minutes to milliseconds

  var newTime = time + delta; // Calculate new time

  var newDate = new Date(newTime); // Get new date object

  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive(); // See Apps Script documentation
  var timezone = spreadsheet.getSpreadsheetTimeZone(); // See Apps Script documentation
  var format = 'HH:mm'; // Set date format for output
  var output = Utilities.formatDate(newDate, timezone, format); // This returns a string
  var target = range.offset(0, 1); // See Apps Script documentation
  target.setValue(output); // See Apps Script documentation
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you are calling `time` inside date (`formatDate`) without actual date format so the sheet is guessing.

```
var formattedDate = Utilities.formatDate(time, "GMT+2", "MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm:ss");
```